# NodeJS correct way to use Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two simple functions:

```
  function GetLinks() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve) {
     request(options, function (error, response, body) {
         if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
             // Print out the response body
             let rawcookies = response.headers['set-cookie'];
             const $ = cheerio.load(body)

             $('.entry-title a[href]').each((index, elem) => {

                 let newItem = (index, $(elem).attr('href'))
                 listOfArticleLinks.push(newItem);

             });

             listOfArticleLinks.forEach(function (item, index, array) {
                 console.log(item);
             });

             resolve();

         }

})})}
```

The function `GetLinks()` sends a request to URL, parse links, add them to the array and write in the console. After writing in the console I call `resolve()` function as Promise is fulfilled.

The second function is:

```
function PrintMe() {
    const initializePromise = GetLinks();
    initializePromise.then(function()
    {
       console.log("it's done");
    })
}
```

The function `PrintMe()` should simply print it's done after `GetLinks()` prints all links to the console.

I'm calling them in this order:

```
GetLinks();
PrintMe();
```

The problem is that sometimes "it's done" is printed in the middle of links and sometimes on the end. Why it does not print "it's done" always on the end? My goal is to wait for GetLinks to be fully finished and then simply call another function.

Comment: Why are you calling `GetLinks` *twice*? Just call it once, and then use `.then` on it

Comment: Also you should put `reject()` into your error handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've posted I can only give you this much of an answers:

```
function GetLinks() {
  // const options = ... // fill in your option here
  return promisifiedRequest(options).then(({response, body}) => {
    let rawcookies = response.headers["set-cookie"]; // unused variable?
    const $ = cheerio.load(body);

    $(".entry-title a[href]").each((index, el) => {
      console.log($(elem).attr("href"));
    });
  });
}

function printMe() {
  console.log("It's done!");
}

// this is your old plain request, but wrapped in a promise
function promisifiedRequest(options) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request(options, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // what is passed here is going to be
        // available in .then call
        resolve({ response, body });
      } else {
        reject("Oopps, can't request");
      }
    });
  });
}

GetLinks()
  .then(printMe)
  .catch(error => console.error(error)); // handle errors
```

Answer (score -1):

`getLinks` is making a request. `printMe` is calling `getLinks` inside of it again and that’s why two promises overlap.
Change `printMe` so that it only prints something.

And then call them like this.

```
getLinks().then(printMe)
```

Comment: What do you expect that `getLinks().then(printMe())` would do?  `printMe()` will still be called right after `getLinks()` is called, so it would not change anything about the problem the OP has. Writing `getLinks().then(printMe())` is like writing `var p1 = getLinks(); var p2 = printMe(); p1.then(p2);`

Comment: I think I had a syntax error which I fixed but I don’t think that’s what you’re pointing at. I know it’ll be called right after that. But this time I told him to change the printMe function so that it only prints. Nothing else.

Comment: U see he was calling getLinks once and then printMe which itself called getLinks. So he was making two requests at the same time.

Comment: I think u missed the part about changing printMe @t.niese